# What is the name of this cable?

Tags: power, identification

What is the name of the next cable:

[image: http://www.jeeptrip.co.il/upload/File959476.jpg]

[image]

(source: http://www.e-shetach.co.il/images/itempics/24to12_large.jpg)

Those are 2 examples of how it looks, can anyone tell me the name of it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the cable or the plug?

Comment: I assume plug/connection. It looks like a BNC on the small end... Though what is it supposed to be? A power adapter?

Comment: Yeah talking about the plug, and I don't think its bnc tho, it seems a bit bigger than bnc. I know it is a cable for things like cars, common in few hummers. And yes Im pretty sure its a power adapt.

Comment: Take a picture showing the whole front of the connector. Also check for any letters/numbers on the shell or inside the connector. There is some resemblance of a MIL connector, unfortunately they come in lots of variants.

Comment: You mean picture of the socket?

Comment: That looks like an MS circular connector - unfortunately, there are about a zillion versions of them.  The cable shown in the referenced picture looks like it has and automotive "Lighter socket" on the other end, so the connector you show probably plugs into a 12 volt outlet in a vehicle.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are right about the lighter socket and the 12v thing, you got any idea on how to get the name of it somehow?

Comment: Don't know if it helps but in this picture( http://electriciantraining.tpub.com/14191/img/14191_75_1.jpg) the socket is the one with 1 contacts with 12-5.

Answer (score 1):

All of googles links to such a plug point to the same image you have on Israeli web pages.  Perhaps it is a military vehicle power point plug that they use.  I would open each page linked in the Google search below and translate it and see if there are any clues.

I'm not sure if this link will work for others as I did the picture upload but I used picture search using your top image so you can do it again. Oh and sorry the Google page may show up in Finnish but the buttons are in the same places.

https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitRzmIIv1RuDTlcGeQcLgTR75wnRVGQ0YaJN4WkvKvu36JTs9oAI0Q78tcizm_1HmEyn_1ANOF-dCP4VjYchH6O9bwD0I9H2zGp2nmw-TQCq1NqCHKZXkI9bHAAEug_1KDMWB3A8A9HMR1xxUne9hY8c22zMCgaiNJDksZjS-olMDRAj-OdaaNS86kb5slklD4d3_1G4HwXxp7JdfwNFaAlT9u6Pwg27KZ-rFd_17mbn6kgvmq_1eO7ZVHr-5XvOjB5NoKsOFq9JaxZvn9eW1qV2567qG_1ma-FtNB5vtB5kghhAvcZyyjxEVukOID2yZvoouhSvOoUNBSmxdksHWNGlG7M0I73JzgmT8NAORlve7VTW6S-mlF5ZwMhmiay8P1zBGIi3H2QrRwjpTWjqrh1PTJxG8YhetEAmEae4bQx9_1Jyot2BDhameRwjMvFcQg3rIAS4xgoC_1YMJstLQUay6bwmAPXmlVwt04mpV2nlLhnODbJMt22lQavDqYlBJLIkYcFoLIxvWizWILxqveO2UuyrVIxp8EU8hcfASNWEEbi362rrkOMBX2_1sO3OPSMBEHpX_1Bm98xdL8t7nij7ciCZJyT9irv0EeVgij5aClrJVmlZgngI26EI1cxnta2DQktL9hom4x130X7KdQW6FAe2WXoFKqtTK9VI_1xJUmIRkgVuTEYaClkBJiH_1tDZs_1gJ2wf8f9sryP_1k5qg1DpHJkuUALhG8oJSS3xoQcLCieQiCKtk94Dv_1ZDrSgIJ6u1fRjecSzXr8hbVx3f6ViDLnMhtxhVyGL43siGIY79465gQMFAW1qPd3cLFWEnLp6wjfstNzFZXuuD1J-O8Uwj2I6zvkw8AStKKhR9W7li7b7JsdpKITWO-DNxYcM7F31V8LTjIkcS12lBjDW5Tem-4ZxGaL1N_1mIhVN6DQpQciAUGXxD8LkA06-Z8-BBny_1Vj-MuIRgq2y0rU8cy2sg2DrpxeX84NkcJgZa7vaXDsfMs_1rxa2iXYbeL4UvVAT97Zht_1XeJeCvi0_1esZ4BsPHRMcKniE3-e0qm6glcK2CgXRcGAw-cerp6qdvt5cWRdboE-w_1LFmoVV1Pe-C-YGkbZpMWW7OcOBNbgOPk_1-FTBwL8kLXVf-DYAuYt9MemAhLwYuo88FnlidB2GTjWLtAAV6JqybzvYZaolZZEahqsYC-r2RaPeGSKp1X_1pt-SCiTzu4IPK6C4G0FNBL8_1btFn4h_1W3hwxEV6K18KGRHzCVch1fLq2d9upGQrQzXsXVq8ruPbQjwrzguilGOxDKxKWWy5Bw5yLuCSbKLh7eTT8n6RdoRsK-wmyZ9e7s1i7F9OEWcsgIfipx7c-QclrdJ40POGUlq91eWrsGcP1cR622O7Qnxlp5J1ehQb5QITeSmXM4XOr9BbQSMmiSxI5w49K3xysZjv8pQ0jdrVQQ&btnG=Hae%20kuvan%20perusteella

Comment: Now that's a very very long link :)

Comment: @Cornelius Did it work for you? Does Google cache my image upload and serve the search results to anyone with that cool long link?

Comment: Yes, it works. It displays the 1024 × 1455 image that is used as search criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't give me any clue about the name of the cable, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: So nobody knows? ^^

Comment: I would try and find a military blog and ask for someone knowledgeable about Israeli military standards.  If it is common with US military connectors (which is likely) then sending the image to a bunch of connector manufacturers for a quote could possibly elicit a part number and then a name.

Comment: Look for Circular MIL spec connectors.  Amphenol is a large manufacturer of them but there are others.  Mouser, and others have a large assortment on the shelf.  http://www.mouser.com/Amphenol/Connectors/Circular-Connectors/Circular-MIL-Spec-Connectors/Circular-MIL-Spec-Connector/_/N-9ulxv?P=1yvsm2bZ1z0zp68Z1yzveggZ1yzv7x2

Comment: Oh, and what do you mean the "Name" of the cable? It is just a power adapter, 12V in, 12V out to  a typical consumer accessory outlet.